# I installed non IC LED recessed lights and now need to insulate part of the ceiling before it is installed, what should I do?

Tags: recessed-lighting

I installed [4" non IC LED recessed lights](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Commercial-Electric-4-in-White-Recessed-Non-IC-New-Construction-Housing-6-Pack-HBR2000BA-6PK/202057595) in a first floor room with 8" clearance during a remodel (no insulation and full access to ceiling space). I later realized that one area of the room with a few of the lights has a small angled roof space above it and needed to be insulated. Rather than switching the housing types, I purchased some [tenmat](http://www.tenmatusa.com/insulation-protection-covers/ff135-recessed-light-draft-stop-cover/) covers. The [internet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n6CHjs8XT7Y) tells me that I need to air-seal them from heat escape (live in Northeastern US), but I need to insulate before the sheetrock goes up. How would I airseal edges with foam after the ceiling goes in? Can I just tack the covers to to the rafters to hold them in place and not airseal? Their [datasheet](http://www.tenmatusa.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/FF135-Installation.pdf) doesn't say anything about foam. I'de rather risk losing heat than have poor airflow and hot fixtures. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

What you *should* do is forget about using those crappy dunce caps and ensure that the fixtures are at least 1/2" away from any wood or combustible material and that insulation is removed and kept away from the fixtures, at least 3" clearance.

Comment: So the heat leakage is not an issue at all, just fire hazard concerns is what you are saying.

Comment: Heat leakage is a concern but is trumped by issues related to overheating. Those caps may be listed as fire resistant but I have heard that they cause the fixture to heat up, which could cause the thermal cut-off device to turn the fixture off or cycle on and off. Non-IC fixtures by code must keep 1/2" from combustibles and 3" from insulation, I am dubious that use of the covers nullifies the requirement.